# How can I put two canvases in the same row in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, canvas

I am currently working on an angular project in which I want to display two graphs on the same row. To display each graph I am using a canvas (I think it is required by chart.js). Unfortunately, it only displays one canvas per row.

I have tried to select the canvases and put `display:inline-block`, wrap them in individual divs and then do `display:inline-block`, and finally wrapping the canvases in one div. Nothing seems to work, and I was unable to find any answers that worked for me.

```css
.div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.canvas {
  display: inline-block;
}

#canvas {
  display: inline-block;
}

#canvas1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.cv {
  display: inline-block;
}


}
```

```html
<div style="width: 40%">
  <canvas class="cv" id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
  <canvas class="cv" id="canvas1" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use flexbox, which you can read more about in [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) excellent CSS-Tricks post.

Just adding `display: flex` on your container class will align the contents in a horizontal line (implicit `flex-direction: row`, if you want them stacked in a column instead you just add `flex-direction: column`).

CSS:

```
.canvas-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 40%;
}

.cv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="canvas-container">
  <canvas class="cv"></canvas>
  <canvas class="cv"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thak you very much, I only had to resize it a bit and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with html only, you are forced to use css. Here's an example how you could manage this:

```
div {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: [column0] 100% [column1]
   grid-template-rows: [row0] 100% [row1]   
}

#canvas {
   grid-area: row0 / column0 / row1 / column1;
}

#canvas1 {
   grid-area: row0 / column0 / row1 / column1;
}
```

So you just assign the same `grid-area` to both canvases. If you want to change the display row just switch those canvases' places or reset the `z-index` in css.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried to apply this fix but I probably did something wrong as it did not work for me. I like the way you answered. It allowed me to learn new things as I am a beginner